# Is $\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 < \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ always true for $\Delta t$ small than one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

We know that the taylor expansion of 
$$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) = a(t)\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 +  \frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 \cdots (1)$$, $a(t)$ can be very big but here I assume that $\Delta t < 1$ so $\Delta t < (\Delta t)^2$.

Are the terms in taylor series always decreasing in higher terms, i.e. 
$a(t)\Delta t < \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 < \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 <  \frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4$

To well approximate $$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) \approx a(t)\Delta t$$

We need the condition $\frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 << a(t) \Delta t$.

But even if the condition holds, the problem may arise even for small but finite $\Delta t$ when extremely large higher derivative occurs:

E.g. $\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 >> \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ or even $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 >> \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$. Is $\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 >> \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2$ always true for $\Delta t$ small than one? If it is then the radius of convergence is just 1?

What would be its radius of convergence of Eq.(1). Does Theorem of Borel apply in this case and how to make use of it?

Comment: You could have it where $a'(t) = 0$ at a specific point $t$ but the higher derivatives are not necessarily zero at that point.

Comment: @Cameron Williams what should i do to well approximate $$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) \approx a(t)\Delta t$$?$\frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 << a(t) \Delta t$ is not enough.

Comment: Just use sufficiently small $\Delta t$. =/ Numerics are far from an exact science. Without knowing anything *a priori* about $a$, it is hard to say much of anything.

Comment: Well I didn't read in detail but such issues always arise when you don't know the function you're dealing with. It could even be that the third derivative doesn't exist and so you can say absolutely nothing about the approximation accuracy.